# wait for java Async calls created in a loop to complete

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have a for loop that creates several Async calls to the client, and in this loop, I want to wait until the client's response is given.

```
for (SocketIOClient soc : server.getRoomOperations(roomName).getClients()) {
                soc.sendEvent("giveRoundData", new AckCallback<String>(String.class) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String s) {
                        System.out.println("Hello 1");
                    }
                });
}
System.out.println("Hello 2")
```

problem is the order of execution.

for example in the code above the output is ( for one iteration ) :

```
Hello 2
Hello 1
```

but I want this to be like :

```
Hello 1
Hello 2
```

is there a way I can wait until every `onSuccess()` is executed?

Comment: You could try blocking the main thread with a **while loop** while the background threads are still running since the `SocketIOClient` doesn't contains a `#join()` method which is used to block the main thread while background threads finnish up.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Synchronizers like CountDownLatch. Use appropriate method that gives the count of the clients when creating the CountDownLatch.

```
    CountDownLatch latch = 
        new CountDownLatch(server.getRoomOperations(roomName).getClients().size());
    for (SocketIOClient soc : server.getRoomOperations(roomName).getClients()) {
                soc.sendEvent("giveRoundData", new AckCallback<String>(String.class) 
    {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String s) {
                        System.out.println("Hello 1");
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                });
    }
    latch.await();
    System.out.println("Hello 2")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't know why this latch.await() method also blocks onSuccess from executing. and another thing that I forgot to say is that this whole for loop and sendEvent method is on another thread other than the main thread. it's on an event listener thread.